# Angular 13 - Could we use useClass with APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular

Angular 13 - Could we use 'useClass' with 'APP_INITIALIZER'..

I have tried...

getting error 'appInits[i]' is not a function..

Please help

Comment: The right way is to use `useFactory`, Do you have any reason you need o `useClass` instead of `useFactory`?

Comment: Actually I have to call another service .. When i use useFactory function, I am not getting the objects of that services..Another error is popping up. That's y i used useclass..

Comment: Yes I tried those.. but in angular 13.3.0 deps not working fine..

Answer (score 1):

You should use `useFactory` instead of `useClass`.
The reason is that `APP_INITIALIZER` expect to get a function but not a class.
From angular.io:

> APP_INITIALIZER : A DI token that you can use to provide one or more **initialization functions.**

The function is executed during the application bootstrap process.

You can read more about `APP_INITIALIZER` in [angular.io](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER).

Example for APP_INITIALIZER with initialization function using multiple services:

```
 {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (
        utils: utilsService,
        authorizationService: AuthorizationService
      ) => {
        return () => {
          return utils.initialize(environment.configFile).then(() => {
            return authorizationService
              .initializePermissions()
              .then((isAuthorized) => {
                if (!isAuthorized) {
                  authorizationService.navigateToErrorPage();
                }
              });
          });
        };
      },
      deps: [UtilsService, AuthorizationService],
      multi: true,
    },
```

Comment: @Bravo i added an example with multiple services in the answer